# LibGDX : Android Game Security

Tags: android, security, libgdx

I am developing game using LibGDX framework . I want to know how to make the game more secure . For example a user with rooted android device can change save .xml file so the game will be hacked , or he/she can use GameKiller or a program like that and change game runtime values (money ,exp etc.). So how can I prevent those?

And the same thing for desktop version , save file is not hidden and the player can find that file on PC too . And can use CheatEngine or other program for hacking and again change runtime values.

Comment: I guess running your game on a server and only persisting data there is not an option? Otherwise you can only make it a "little harder" to cheat, but you never can prevent it completely. If you need to operate on a user owned device.

Comment: And how can I make it a little harder?

Comment: Obfuscate your code/save file. An option would be to "encrypt" the save file and obfuscate the key in your code. Encryption could be a simple XOR or shift. But you should not put to much effort into it, since if your game gets popular, then it will be cracked, the crackers will then most likely publish their work, etc... Code obfuscation can be done through programs, but that is most likely an opinion based question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not storing private/important data but only want to make it hard to hack your game (for example by changing xml with levels of your game) you can implement encryption basen on [GWT Crypto library](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/)

The way you are initializing encryptor is:

```
    //this will be used for encrypting and decrypting strings
    private TripleDesCipher encryptor;  

    ...

    //creating key for encryptor
    TripleDesKeyGenerator generator = new TripleDesKeyGenerator();
    byte[] key = generator.decodeKey("04578a8f0be3a7109d9e5e86839e3bc41654927034df92ec"); //you can pass your own string here

    //initializing encryptor with generated key
    encryptor = new TripleDesCipher();
    encryptor.setKey(key);

    ...
```

And way of using it:

```
    private String encryptString(String string)
    {
        try 
        {
            string = encryptor.encrypt( string );
        } 
        catch (DataLengthException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InvalidCipherTextException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return string;
    }

    private String decryptString(String string)
    {
        try 
        {
            string = encryptor.decrypt(string);
        } 
        catch (DataLengthException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidCipherTextException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return string;
    }
```

I also recommend you not to use XMLs but JSONs - they are more convenient and weights less. [Read how to handle it here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON)

---

Remember that generally client-side encryption is not very good idea and always can be hacked in some way - but I'm pretty sure that if it is not about money noone will think it worth.

If you are interested in more advanced way of keeping your data save the best idea would be sending all data by SSL and save it in some well-guard server - although I'm not very sure if Libgdx has any good SSL mechanism and don't know 3rd part libraries that I could recommend.

The example of service to keep files can be [Shephertz](http://api.shephertz.com/apis/file_storage.php) (I was using their nice AppWarp and going to implement this one in my app also).

Comment: Note that this encryption provides the same security in this context as XORING with one byte. Why? Java is to easy to decompile. So I just decompile the jar/apk (there are even online tools for that), copy the code and decrypt/encrypt the save file. One should at least try to hide/obfuscate the key, so that it is "harder" to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can use those for runtime

1. Twin variables

Twin for a cheatengine and gamekiller

```
int health=15;
int twinhealth=15;  
if(HPtaken()) 
{
  health+=10;//those twins will always change together 
  twinhealth+=10;
}
if(health!=twinhealth)//if they are different this means there is hack attempt
{
//punishment for hacker
}
```

2. Crypted variables

Actually its not a crypt its just little change on variables so hacker cant change easly via gamekiller or cheatengine.

```
int health=15*7;
int twinhealth=15*7;

if(HPtaken()) 
{
  health+=10*7;//those twins will always change together 
  twinhealth+=10*7;
}
drawhealth( health/7 );// So hacker going to see and search wrong value on cheatengine
```

3. Crypted twin variables :D

Hacker ban freeze and change both twin with a same value. So at least one of the twins will be crypted.

```
int health=15;
int twinhealth=15*5;    
if(HPtaken()) 
{
  health+=10;//those twins will always change together 
  twinhealth+=10*5;
}
if(health!=twinhealth*5)//if they are different this means there is hack attempt
{
//punishment for hacker
}
```

Of course hacker can decompile apk and hack your game but it makes little bit harder to hack game. By the way you can use random variables for editing variables.

You can apply to xml or preferences those but you can use little bit complicated crypt because speed not an issue since you only import/export few times.